# Cannot create/upload or open notebooks using Google Colab

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory, drive

I have the following issues:

- I cannot create a new Notebook using Google Colab
- I cannot open/upload a Notebook using Google Colab
- I can see Notebooks such as Welcome To Google Colaboratory
- Until yesterday everything worked perfectly
- I assume that I can open everything that is not linked to my Google Drive

I get the following error:

Notebook loading error
There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.

Could not fetch resource at https://clients6.google.com/drive/v2beta/files/1RePbtAcs2yXW5iEl2qAS-xsGNbP_6T7u?alt=media&key=AIzaSyCN_sSPJMpYrAzC5AtTrltNC8oRmLtoqBk&%24unique=1591516436185: 403 Forbidden
https://drive.google.com/drive/?action=locate&id=1RePbtAcs2yXW5iEl2qAS-xsGNbP_6T7u&authuser=0

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have tried open a notebook in incognito mode and still not working.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem yet? I am having the same problem and am also unsure of what to do.

Comment: Well it was indeed a problem with my Google drive permissions. Most of the time the Colab directory is private and cannot be accessed, in my case it was actaully the the notebook file that somehow became private. I made it public and the issues was resolved. So check the permissions you have granted for the Colab folder or the files inside. As far as I remember I have choosen: anyone with the link can edit/read/write depending on the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response of "Forbidden" indicates that you have a permissions issue. You say you tried to open the notebook in incognito mode and failed, like that was unexpected, so the problem is not your authentication.

Either your drive permissions, folder permissions, or file permissions are not set correctly to allow public access.

Answer (score 0):

Old Pro has said it right, I believe, you might need to allow Google Colab access to your Google Drive all over again, I would delete the extension, and reinstall the extension. Accept the permissions it's asking for to your Google Drive. Then try to create a Google Colab Notebook.

Reference: These are just my thoughts after working with Google Colab myself.